# Access toolbar textview from Fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have navigation drawer with custom toolbar. I am trying to access textView in toolbar in Fragment and set a text in fragment. Is this possible, if so how?

Here is the toolbar.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:id="@+id/toolbar"
 style="@style/ActionBar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
 android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
 app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutID">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/register_title"
        android:textColor="@color/blackText"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/action_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/logoactionbar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to set toolbar_title's text according to fargment I have clicked. How do I access them in Fragment.

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Where have you included toolbar? From there you can find it in activity or fragment

Comment: @Harry: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please try this one

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
textToolHeader = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.textToolHeader);
textToolHeader.setText("Text which you want");
```

Hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked but how could it take the toolbar reference when I don't have any in my fragment XML?

Comment: Create a common toolbar and use it as common

Answer (score 0):

make `public textChanger()` method in your activity

```java
public class YourActiviy extends Activity {

Toolbar toolbar;
Textview text;
textToolHeader.setText("Text which you want");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    text = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.text);
}

public void changeToolBarText(String txt){
    text.setText(txt);
}
```

}

and in your fragment use

```java
((YourActiviy) getActivity()).changeToolBarText("what ever you want");
```

to change that textview.

as an sample, in fragment;

```java
public class test extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ((YourActivity) getActivity()).changeToolBarText("what ever you want");

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This currently works for me at the moment. just call in the `onCreateView`:

```
AppBarLayout toolbar = (AppBarLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
TextView topBack = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.back);
```